# Rules related to dispute on creditcard between Customers Bank and the Merchants Bank

Tags: credit-card, mastercard, chargeback

I purchased certain domains with sav.com, but the merchant had site latency and the same was reported by many customers on Trustpilot.com. My credit card was charged but domains not posted on my account.

I requested a chargeback, but the merchant bank responded that the customer is successfully able to loggedIn, and provided IP’s and thus availing the services.

My bank sent me a note that If I am not satisfied I can re dispute it within 7-days. I provided all the necessary information to the bank within 48 Hours, and clearly confirmed that I didn’t purchase any service, but a domain, which is an Intellectual Property not a service. I also additionally clarified that I also didn’t purchase any membership as account creation with the domain registrar sav.com is a free process, and not chargeable.

Regarding the documents shared I have an email communications with the merchant where the merchant in written correspondence has clearly stated that I do not have any active domains in my account, in another ticket the merchant has also confirmed over email that the domains are available in the open market to be booked by anyone.

But, Now the bank is saying that we acknowledge that the documents shared are relevant, but the merchant's bank is not accepting them. I suspect that this can't be the case and probably my Bank in India: CitiBank would have failed the re-dispute representation in time.

**Question:**
The card is a Citibank's + Mastercard. How banks create disputes, probably they must be a member of some International membership forums/Banking Ombudsman, which should have set a certain rule book to come to a decision in case of disputes. How is it possible that the merchant's bank will discard relevant proof such as: **Merchant's** acceptance in written correspondence that no Intellectual property such as domain are active in my account.

If, I can get the clarity, I can speak to the bank in more assertive and well articulated manner.

Connecting dot: [Reference](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/78593/credit-card-charged-but-domain-not-booked-by-a-domain-registrar-where-should-i-g)

Comment: Did you try contacting sav.com first and showing them that you were charged but didn't get the domains? If you have an email from them saying "We didn't take your money", then that's a powerful piece of information to use for the chargeback - and if they say they _did_ take your money, but also didn't provide you what you paid for, then that's _also_ useful. Simply saying "No, you're not currently paying for anything" isn't much proof by itself. Besides that, if you keep pushing the chargeback, your bank will probably just end up paying you back and eating the cost, but it may take a while.